# if else inside for loop in c but else statement doesn't work

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```
for (int i = 1; i < 22; i++){
        
    if(i<=99 && i>=0){
        printf("enter an age");
        scanf("%d", &ages[i]);
    }
    else{
            printf("enter a valid number");
    }
       
}
```

When I enter a number outside the if statement such as 999, my program still accepts it instead of printing enter a valid number message. thanks in advance.

When I enter a number outside the if statement such as 999, my program still accepts it instead of printing enter a valid number message. thanks in advance.

Comment: You've written your code statements in the wrong order, so you are checking `i` before you read a value from the user.  Also, it's not `i` you should be checking; your scanning into `ages[i]`, not `i`.

Comment: You must always check what [`scanf` ***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: And I really recommend that you kind of forget that plain `scanf` even exists. Use `fgets` to read a whole line into a string (and check what it returns as well). Then use either `sscanf` or `strtol` to convert the string with validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as the 'i' is the index of the 'ages' array, you are allowing values with a range of 0-99. So, if the value is out oof this range also, it will still be stored in the 'ages' array. It won't display the warning message (enter a valid number) also. Instead, you can try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 22; i++){
    printf("enter an age: ");
    scanf("%d", &ages[i]);
    if(ages[i] > 99 || ages[i] < 0){
        printf("enter a valid number\n");
        i--;
    }
}
```